# Memory Management - Deleting a vector of objects retaining a pointer to previous element of same vector

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

New to c++.

Suppose I have a `std::vector<Foo*> foos;`, `Foo` being

```cpp
// This is a virtual class in my case.
class Foo {
private:
  Foo* m_previous_foo { nullptr };
public:
  // Should this class have a destructor destroying its m_previous_foo?
  // IMO this seems incorrect, since a removal of 
  // Foo from Bar would delete a Foo I still want to retain, I guess?

  // Called by Bar's constructor, necessary for my use case.
  void set_previous(Foo* previous_foo) { m_previous_foo = previous_foo; };

  const bool previous_is_valid() const { return m_previous_foo != nullptr; };
};
```

and a `Bar` owning that vector:

```cpp
class Bar {
private:
  std::vector<Foo*> m_foos;
public:
 ~Bar() {
   // What do I do here?

   // My idea 1:
   for (auto p_foo : m_foos) {
     if (p_foo->previous_is_valid()) {
       delete p_foo->get_previous();
     } else { // Previous pointer is already nullptr, only delete pointer
       delete p_foo;
     }
   }

   // My idea 2:
   for (auto p_foo : m_foos) {
     delete p_foo;
   }

   // My idea 3: essentially the same as idea 1 but checking for index 0
   // as the only case where we delete the pointer.
 }
}
```

EDIT: Example of how this vector looks with 4 elements:

```cpp
vector[0] = Foo with m_previous_foo = nullptr
vector[1] = Foo with m_previous_foo = &vector[0];
vector[2] = Foo with m_previous_foo = &vector[1];
vector[3] = Foo with m_previous_foo = &vector[2];
```

My guess is that all of these are incorrect, since no matter how I delete these pointers, they get invalidated in the "next" Foo, i.e. the Foo owning the now deleted pointer.

EDIT: I'm still in training wheels and I've read about smart pointers, however, I do not understand them, and I reckon that I should understand pointer management prior to utilizing smarter abstractions.

Comment: First of all, `delete` will *not* set a pointer to `nullptr`. Secondly, passing a null pointer to `delete` is okay (it simply does nothing). Thirdly, will "previous foo" be in the vector as well? The solution to your problem depends on that.

Comment: Ah okay, I had no idea delete on nullptr does nothing. I will update the question with previous foo info.

Comment: Why do you need a pointer to the previous `Foo` in each `Foo`? Why not only have a `std::vector<Foo>` (or `std::list<Foo>` if you need the actual `Foo`s to not relocate) and use iterators to step back and forth in the container?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I might be able to redesign the algorithm, but basically, [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) requires the output of the previous implementation of Foo* to compute the owner's output.

Comment: Since all "previous foo" will be in the vector as well, alternative 2 seems like be simplest solution.